# Is there REST API to determine version of installed TFS server?

Tags: api, tfs-2015

I have two versions of TFS installed TFS 2013 and TFS 2015. I need a way to determine the version and then make appropriate REST API calls. For 2013, there is api-version 1.0 and for 2015 there is api-version=2.0 for builds. I need to find out the version of TFS server using REST API calls. I have checked all APIs on microsoft API page, but none give me any information related to TFS server version

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this party, but I had a similar question and found the following:
Apparently there is backward compatibility. I was querying my build server pools with the following:

http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=4.1

This returned unformatted JSON, as expected.

By accident I tried
http://tfs2018:8080/tfs/_apis/distributedtask/pools?api-version=4.2

This returned a 'Not found' page.  On testing I notieced that any request greater than the API version produced a 'Not found' page.  Every request less than the API version down to 1.0 produced unformatted JSON.

I'll admit this is not very elegant, but a simple test should tell you what you want to know about the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Rest API is for VSO; as you're working with on-premise TFS, there is no Rest API, you need to use TFS API.

Secondly, [TestManagementServiceVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.testmanagementserviceversion.aspx) has members from V1~V6, you can try using it to get TFS server version.

Comment: This is not correct. TFS 2013 had some unsupported REST APIs and TFS 2015 supports API versions 1 and 2.